# How to create authentication in Angular 2 with Laravel Passport?

Tags: laravel, angular, authentication

I have a problem to find way to make authentication for my angular 2 app. I have API in laravel, and tried to use laravel passport(via password grant). I tested it on Postman and now I need to connect it with angular. I've started looking for some library to do it, but i find only this https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc

Do you have any ideas on how to connect this? I can not cope with that.

Answer (score 1):

You can make service like this , don't forget to assign the client id and secret.

> userservice.ts

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Http, Headers, Response} from '@angular/http';
import {User} from './user';


@Injectable()
export class UserService {

    constructor(private http: Http) {
    }

    private oauthUrl = "http://server.techalin.com/oauth/token";
    private usersUrl = "http://server.techalin.com/api/users";

    getAccessToken() {
        var headers = new Headers({
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json"
        });

        let postData = {
            grant_type: "password",
            client_id: 2,
            client_secret: "RGNmOzt7WQ8SdNiCcJKKDoYrsFqI2tudopFjOJU3",
            username: "albanafmeti@gmail.com",
            password: "password",
            scope: ""
        }

        return this.http.post(this.oauthUrl, JSON.stringify(postData), {
            headers: headers
        })
            .map((res: Response) => res.json())
            .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
    }

    getUsers(accessToken: string): Observable<User[]> {

        var headers = new Headers({
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken,
        });

        return this.http.get(this.usersUrl, {
            headers: headers
        })
            .map((res: Response) => res.json())
            .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
    }
}
```

and use this service to other component like this

```js
  import 'UserService' from './user.service';
  export class ExampleCompoent{
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {
        this.userService.getAccessToken()
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.getUsers(data.access_token)
            });
    }

    getUsers(accessToken: string) {
        this.userService.getUsers(accessToken)
            .subscribe(
                users => {
                    this.users = users;
                    console.log(users);
                });
    }
    }
```

read more on this [link](http://albanafmeti.com/2016/using-laravel-passport-with-an-angular2-client-app/)